# Android there's any issues about security?

Tags: android, security

I'm passing passwords by webservice. My question is very simple: there's any way of anyone getting those passwords, by sniffer or something?

The passwords I'm passing are essentially to connect to database. I can't pass an hash password because then I wouldn't be able to connect to database.

Also, there's any way of getting access to SQLiteDatabase generated for any application?

Thanks.

Comment: You found a good solution to it?

Comment: No. I found that you can access to any SQLiteDatabase from any application and read the data (which is very unsecure), and also it's possible to decrypt the APK code. There's a feature called ProGuard http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html, which help to obfuscate the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS. That way you don't have to care about the password being traced by packet sniffers. This link might help with the common pitfalls : http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Comment: Thanks but I can't use HTTPs.

Comment: why? Any specific reason? That is the best way to secure the data going out of your app